# Monitoring a Directory for New Sub Directories

Tags: bash, perl, directory, monitor

There is a large shared directory on a Linux machine that contains a number of projects. Once per day I need to determine if any new directories have been created since the previous day.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Does anyone have any suggestions? I am unable to install additional tools and would prefer a Bash script or something in Perl. Ideally, I would be able to access the file/directory creation date but it seems that only the date last modified is recorded.

I am trying to do something like this, but I can't seem to massage this to work properly. There must be a simple solution.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/Project/working

if [ ! -e /tmp/new_games_diff_0 ]
then
    echo "First run... cannot determine if there any new games"
    ls -1 > /tmp/new_games_diff_0
    exit
fi

ls -1 > /tmp/new_games_diff_1
gvimdiff /tmp/new_games_diff_1 /tmp/new_games_diff_0 &

cp /tmp/new_games_diff_1 /tmp/new_games_diff_0
```

Comment: What's the actual ultimate goal here?

Comment: I have to process certain documents specific to the directories that are created. Each day I end up checking to see if the folder for each document has been created. If I had a list of new directories that were created I could save 5-10 minutes each day

Comment: In which case `find -mtime -1` might be appropriate.

Comment: The directories that already exist are modified frequently.

Comment: note that you _may_ want to look into FAM/GAMIN if you need to detect immediately when directories get created, but it sounds like that's unnecessary for your current problem.  (E.g. https://people.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/python.html) ; this is a tool that allows you to have an app that gets events when files are created (or accessed, deleted, etc. but you can set up filters for just creation if you want)

Comment: Okay I've made a note, that could potentially be useful in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct - linux doesn't (necessarily) track any specific creation times. So you're going to need to compare 'before' and 'after.

Perl has a nice mechanism for this in the form of hashes, and the built in [`Storable`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html) module.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Storable;

my $path    = "/home/Project/working";
my $seen_db = "~/.seen_files";

my %seen;
if ( -f $seen_db ) { %seen = %{ retrieve $seen_db } }

foreach my $entry ( glob("$path/*") ) {
    if ( -d $entry ) {
        print "New entry: $entry\n" unless $seen{$entry}++;
    }
}

store( \%seen, $seen_db );
```

If you want to store some file metadata in your db - like `mtime` then it'll be worth looking at the [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) function.

However this might be a little overkill - as you might simply find that `find` will do the trick:

```
find /home/Project/working -mtime -1 -type d -maxdepth 1 -ls
```

(You can also use `-exec` as find option to perform an action on each of the files, like running a script).

Comment: This is precisely what I am looking for, I love this... I'm running into an error however "Can't create ~/.seen_files: No such file or directory at ./check_new_games line 20". I did try creating the file and not creating the file

Comment: You shouldn't need to create it - the script does that. It might actually cause problems if you do, because it'll try and read it if it exists.  But you'll need to set `$seen_db` to a valid file path - I just made a guess. Your home drive for example (`~/.seen_db` should evaluate to 'in your home drive' but if that's not working, try something else). (Or you could put it in `/home/Project/working/.seen_db` maybe?).

Comment: Okay for some reason "~/.seen_files" gave me a problem but I switched this to "/home/username/.seen_games" and it worked fine. THANK YOU! First time on StackOverflow and amazed at the fast response.

Comment: You asked a good question, with a clear problem spec and showed a solid attempt at it yourself. That elicits good responses generally.